# Cytoscape.js grid layout not using grid positions

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, cytoscape.js

I'm new to Cytoscape.js, and I'm trying to make the grid layout work. I've got nine nodes in the following format:

```
{ 
  data: {
    id: 'a1',
    name:'CCDS 4.1 (new)',
    width: 0,
    color: '#BD4A3B'
  },
  position: {
    x: 1,
    y: 0
  },
  group: 'nodes'
}
```

I would expect this to show up on the second row, first column of my grid.

I've also got the following layout options specified.

```
layout: {
  name: 'grid',
  position: function(node) { return node.position; }
}
```

The output I get, though, doesn't honor any of my grid position, and just creates a row of 5 nodes and a row of 4 nodes. I've also tried without the `position` option above, but this doesn't seem to help. I know I'm missing something simple... :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`position` refers to the `location` of a node in **{x, y}** terms, i.e the `position` on the screen/viewport. Here is the documentation for `position` http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/position.

You would have to do specify the `row` and `column` in the data and access it using `ele.data(...)`

```
{ 
  data: {
    id: 'a1',
    name:'CCDS 4.1 (new)',
    width: 0,
    color: '#BD4A3B',
    row: 1,
    col: 0
  },
  group: 'nodes'
}
```

And you can set the `row` and `column` in the layout options

```
layout: {
  name: 'grid',
  position: function(node) { 
    return {
     row: node.data('row'),
     col: node.data('col')
    } 
  }
}
```